# fscanf on string causes segmentation fault

Tags: c, file, segmentation-fault, scanf

I have a three row input file.
First row is an int, the second row is ints with space, the third row is a string.

I have to scan them than manipulate the string based on the ints.

My problem is that I can scan the ints, but scanning the string causes segmentation fault at fclose.

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h> 

int main()
{
    FILE* in = fopen("be.txt", "r");
    FILE* out = fopen("ki.txt", "w");

    if(in==NULL){
        printf("Error opening in!\n");
        return -1;
    }
    if(out==NULL){
        printf("Error opening out!\n");
        return -1;
    }

    int brknglength, i;

    fscanf(in, "%d", &brknglength);

    printf("%d\n", brknglength);

    int* seed[brknglength];
    seed[brknglength] = malloc(sizeof(int[brknglength]));

    for(i = 0; i < brknglength; i++){
        if (fscanf(in, "%d", &seed[i]) != 1) {
            printf("%d", i);
        }
        printf("%d.: %d \n", i, seed[i]);

    }

    char string;

    fscanf(in, "%s", &string);


    free(seed[brknglength]);

    fclose(in);
    fclose(out);
    return 0;
}
```

What causes the segmentation fault?

Comment: `char string;` is only a single character. `fscanf(in, "%s", &string);` expects an array of large enough size, in which case it should be `fscanf(in, "%s", string);` without the `&` operator.

Comment: `int* seed[brknglength]; seed[brknglength] = malloc(sizeof(int[brknglength]));` is wrong. Use just `int seed[brknglength];` and remove the `free(seed...);` too.

Comment: I think you should change `int* seed[brknglength]` to `int seed[brknglength]`. Otherwise, you've got yourself an array of uninitialized pointers, each of which you are technically initializing using `fscanf` (most likely with a value which does not point to a properly allocated block of memory in your program).

Comment: Unlike most higher level languages, C doesn't have a built-in string type. Study strings in your C programming book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first Problem appears here:

```
int* seed[brknglength];
```

This defines an array of `int` pointers on the stack.

```
seed[brknglength] = malloc(sizeof(int[brknglength]));
```

This initializes the element *behind* the array and overwrites your stack.
To fix it, use either:

```
int seed[brknglength]; /* use without free(seed) */
```

or:

```
int *seed = malloc(sizeof(int[brknglength]));
/* ... */
free(seed);
```

The latter also works for compilers, which do not support variable length arrays.

---

Your second problem is reading a string into a single `char` variable, which also overwrites the stack. Try something like:

```
char string[100];
fscanf(in, "%99s", &string);
```

Be aware, that `"%s"` stops at whitespace. Use something like `"%99[^\t\n]"` to define your own separators, or `"%99c"` for a fixed length string.

The GNU Compiler offers the modifier `"m"` (=allocate memory) as a convenient non-standard extension for all these cases:

```
char *string;
fscanf(in, "%ms", &string);
/* ... */
free(string);
```

Answer (score 2):

> `int* seed[brknglength];`
>   
>      `seed[brknglength] = malloc(sizeof(int[brknglength]));`

It looks like what you tried to do here is make `seed` a pointer to an array of `int` and allocate space for it. However, that is the wrong syntax. Because `[ ]` has higher precedence than `*`, `int* seed[brknglength];` defines an array of pointers to `int`. Also, the name of the object is `seed`, not `seed[brknglength]`, so you would assign a value to it with `seed = …`, not with `seed[brknglength] = …`.

To make a pointer to an array and allocate space for it, use:

```
int (*seed)[brknglength];
seed = malloc(sizeof *seed);
```

Those can be combined (which is not a violation of the above note about using `seed =` for assignment—initialization has a special syntax):

```
int (*seed)[brknglength] = malloc(sizeof *seed);
```

However, you probably do not want that. If `size` is a pointer to an array, then you have to use `*seed` wherever you want to refer to the array. So `fscanf(in, "%d", &seed[i])` would have to be `fscanf(in, "%d", &(*seed)[i])`.

Instead of making `seed` a pointer to an array, just make it a pointer to an `int`, and allocate space for as many `int` as you want:

```
int *seed = malloc(brknglength * sizeof *seed);
```

Then you can use `seed[i]` for element `i` of the array instead of having to use `(*seed)[i]`.

> `char string;`

That defines `string` to be a single `char`. But `fscanf(in, "%s", &string);` reads as many characters as the input has until a white-space character. So you need to pass `fscanf` a pointer to the first of many `char`. You can either declare `string` to be an array:

```
char string[100];
```

or a pointer to space that is allocated:

```
char *string = malloc(100 * sizeof *string);
```

Then you can use `fscanf(in, "%s", string);`. Note that you do not want to pass `&string`. That is the address of the array or of the pointer, depending on how you defined `string`. You want to pass the address of the first character, which is `&string[0]`, or, equivalently, `string`. (If `string` is an array, it is automatically converted in this expression to a pointer to its first element, so it is equivalent to `&string[0]`.)

Note that `fscanf` will read as many character as the input contains until a white-space character appears. That can exceed whatever size you provide for `string`. So you need to ensure the input does not have too many characters or tell `fscanf` to limit how much it reads, which you can do with:

```
fscanf(in, "%99s", string);
```

or:

```
int n = 99;
fscanf(in, "%*s", n, string);
```

Note that `fscanf` should be told to read at most one character less than the space in `string` because it needs to add a terminating null character.

To free these objects, use:

```
free(seed);
free(string); // (If defined as a pointer, not an array.)
```